# How to deploy Camel route in Azure Functions using Quarkus?

Tags: azure-functions, apache-camel, quarkus

I need assistance with the following.  I am not sure if I am setting up my Camel Quarkus application correctly in order for it to deploy to Azure Functions.

I have looked at the Quarkus examples of deploying Quarkus application in Azure Functions.

https://quarkus.io/guides/azure-functions-http

I am trying to implement a Camel Quarkus application on Azure Functions.  I started off by creating an application from the following archetype.

```
mvn archetype:generate \
    -DarchetypeGroupId=io.quarkus \
    -DarchetypeArtifactId=quarkus-azure-functions-http-archetype \
    -DarchetypeVersion=2.15.1.Final
```

I have deployed the above application to Azure functions and it works.  I now try to extend this application to invoke a Camel route (i have included the Camel Quarkus dependencies in the application POM).  It builds and the sample endpoint is invocable locally on the IDE.

While the deployment to Azure function also works, however when I invoke this endpoint that is now hosted on Azure, I get the following message.

Has anyone experienced this or have any examples of setting up a Camel Quarkus application for Azure Functions deployment?

https://quarkus-getting-started-1671721071201.azurewebsites.net/api/test

Response
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.`‹í½`I–%&/mÊ{JõJ×àt¡€`$Ø@ìÁˆÍæ’ìiG#)«*ÊeVe]f@Ìí¼÷Þ{ï½÷Þ{ï½÷º;N'÷ßÿ?\fdlöÎJÚÉž!€ªÈ?~|?"þ`

Here is the example Java class that was added to the application.

```
package my.test;

import org.apache.camel.builder.endpoint.EndpointRouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.model.rest.RestBindingMode;


public class MyTestFunction extends EndpointRouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        restConfiguration().bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json);
        
        rest("/test")
                .get().to("direct:hello");

        from("direct:hello").transform().constant("hello world");


    }
    
}
```

The azure function binding looks like this.

```
{
  "scriptFile" : "../quarkus-getting-started-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar",
  "entryPoint" : "io.quarkus.azure.functions.resteasy.runtime.Function.run",
  "bindings" : [ {
    "type" : "httpTrigger",
    "direction" : "in",
    "name" : "req",
    "route" : "{*path}",
    "methods" : [ "GET", "POST", "HEAD", "PUT", "OPTIONS", "DELETE" ],
    "dataType" : "binary",
    "authLevel" : "ANONYMOUS"
  }, {
    "type" : "http",
    "direction" : "out",
    "name" : "$return"
  } ]
}
```

Comment: when you run local ```mvn quarkus:dev``` can you get response from http://localhost:8080/api/hello ?